# How can we test the force field (parameter) for a complex?

Tags: molecular-dynamics, computational-chemistry, forcefields

I built a force field for a complex. How can I check if the force field is working well or no?

I did a short molecular dynamics using AMBER only for the complex using the parameters I built. It worked well, but what can I do more ?

Comment: How did you build the force field? I think usually the force field is checked against experimental data like radial distribution functions, equilibrium constants, ligand exchange rates etc.

Comment: I have a complex that contain transitional metal, I want to do MD later, therefore, I build force field and parameter. There is no experimental data. I want to see if this force field works well for the complex or no?

Comment: I don't know how you can validate parameters if there are no experimental data. Do you have QM data? as in from high-level QM calculations.

Comment: I have QM data.

Comment: compare forces and energies against quality QM results. geometry optimize both MM and QM structures, calculate the RMSD for atomic positions.

Comment: +1. How did this go over the last few months? Have you found an answer now? Please update us! Thanks :)

Comment: @NikeDattani.
I can include what I found as an answer. let me know what do you think?

Answer (score 2):

I tested the force field in two ways.

1-I performed a short-time MD for my system in vacuum using my force field and the same time of AIMD simulation for my system. Then I started to compare the evolution of the distance, the angle, and the dihedral between MD and AIMD. For example, `Ru-N`, `N1-Ru-N2` etc.

2-Following the first step, I attempted to add more to compare by calculating the spectrum. As a result, I took 50 structures from the MD and AIMD simulations, ran the calculation, and plotted the spectrum for both (MD and AIMD).